# Why can dieties see "Star Souls" but humans cannot?

Tags: magic, fantasy-races, gods, supernatural

### **Star Souls**

This is an idea I have been bouncing off in my head, and I want some feedback. The idea is that the beauty in this universe are determinded by "star souls". They are created from dying stars, and people can't see these sould, but our eyes and senses are attuned to certain types of souls, which are why different people see different things as beautiful. The deities can see them, all but one, the protagnist. They (deities are genderless) are super depressed, as they can't see the beauty in this world. They go throughout the galaxy, and find nothing. Degected, they go back to their home base, but as they are about to give up hope, but then see something beautiful. The story ends without telling you what the beautiful thing is. To make the reader think. ANYways. The deities aren't all powerful. Similar to Norse gods, they are mortal, and still have to abide by the laws of physics and the universe. They are just powerful beings that happen to use Earth as like a nature reserve, or a place that is more to be enjoyed than to be colonized.

My question, which I can't seem to think of an answer of:

1. What make humans unable to see the souls, but deities can? Outside of magic.

Comment: It's considered bad form to accept an answer within minutes of posting a question, this site has contributors worldwide so it's considered polite to allow at least 24 hours for other answers from other time-zones.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'm still new here. I'll be sure to not do that in the future. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: You might find it helpful to take the [tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour), some of our ways can seem strange if you don't :)

Comment: I should point out the reason this question is being downvoted/voted-to-close is it is "too story based". That means the question sounds like "I need ideas for this" and there is no way to judge which solution to your problem is better. This is especially important for questions about (all powerful?) deities unless you put some restrictions on them.

Comment: Okay. I got the restrictions on them. I want to make this story a fun read that people can relate to, which needs acurate laws and other things of that sort. I'm sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

**Humans cannot see Souls.**

The fact you have called these things *souls* already answers your question. Humans cannot see any sort of soul directly. We can only observe the side effects of one being present. For example we can see the difference between a dead (no soul) or a living person (soul) because the second moves around and makes noise.

Deities can see souls because they are deities. They have powers that mortals don't have.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said the phrase "outside of magic" in your question, another approach you can take is that deities in your universe can see in higher spatial dimensions or certain types of fields in physics, whether it's the classical electromagnetic field, or something else.

We humans are used to three spatial dimensions, but we can observe a one dimensional object (a line), and a two dimensional object. Each consecutive dimension is a slice of the dimension above it, and an entity that exists or operates in specific dimensions cannot see the whole of an entity in a higher dimension.

Consider that the star soul is only visible to entities that can operate in the dimensions above - perhaps the deity's representation to us is only a slice of their real 4D or 5D bodies, and the star soul exists in their dimension and not ours, even though it's still in our universe.

Alternatively, consider that the star soul can only be detected by the evolved central nervous system of the deity, kind of like how a person with tetrachromacy can observe ultraviolet, or how animals can detect things like magnetic fields, but on a much higher level. If your deity is a living organism, it's okay for this to be something other than visible light, because brains and central nervous systems can render these disturbances as anything, including visual information.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a question of "seeing" souls.  It is more about understanding what is being seen.

Isaac Newton lived from 1642 till 1727.

For millennia prior to his announced his theory of gravity, people observed apples falling from trees.

Only in the years after his announcement did they see gravity.